# Finding time complexity of recursive formula

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to find time complexity (big O) of a recursive formula.

I tried to find a solution, you may see the formula and my solution below:

[image: formula]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?  Hint: recurrence relation.

Comment: Everything is in the attached photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Brenner said, your last assumption is false. Here is why: Let's take the definition of `O(n)` from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) (using `n` instead of `x`):

> `f(n) = O(n)` if and only if there exist constants `c`, `n0` s.t. `|f(n)| <= c |g(n)|`, for all`n >= n0`.

We want to check if `O(2^n^2) = O(2^n)`. Clearly, `2^n^2` is in `O(2^n^2)`, so let's pick `f(n) = 2^n^2` and check if this is in `O(2^n)`. Put this into the above formula:

`exists c, n0: 2^n^2 <= c * 2^n for all n >= n0`

Let's see if we can find suitable constant values `n0` and  `c` for which the above is true, or if we can derive a contradiction to proof that it is not true:

Take the log on both sides:

`log(2^n^2) <= log(c * 2 ^ n)`

Simplify:

`2 ^n log(2) <= log(c) + n * log(2)`

Divide by `log(2)`:

`n^2 <= log(c)/log(2) * n`

It's easy to see know that there is no `c`, `n0` for which the above is true for all `n >= n0`, thus `O(2^n^2) = O(n^2)` is not a valid assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If our answers were helpful, you can up-vote them and accept one! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The last assumption you've specified with the question mark is false! Do not make such assumptions.

The rest of the manipulations you've supplied seem to be correct. But they actually bring you nowhere.

You should have finished this exercise in the middle of your draft:

```
T(n) = O(T(1)^(3^log2(n)))
```

And that's it. That's the solution!

You could actually claim that

```
3^log2(n) == n^log2(3) ==~ n^1.585
```

and then you get:

```
T(n) = O(T(1)^(n^1.585))
```

which is somewhat similar to the manipulations you've made in the second part of the draft.
So you can also leave it like this. But you cannot mess with the exponent. Changing the value of the exponent changes the big-O classification.

Comment: Thank you very much